# Django how to ManyToManyField show in template as Select widget

Tags: html, django

My models.py:

```
class Model2(models.Model)
    choice_field = models.ManyToManyField(to=Model)
```

my views.py:

```
def func(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
        return.........................................
   And so what I need to do with form request?
```

my template.html:

```
<div>
    {{ form.choice_field }}
</div>
```

I get a values list and can a scroll and choose what I want. But i want to use Select with options for this values in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define widget for each field of your model manually. Assuming you using built-in `ModelForm` your code in `forms.py` can be something like this:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select

class Model2Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = [
            'choice_field',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'choice_field': Select(),
        }
```

Comment: Men Respect! I was tried to use widgets with other field 2 days ago and forget, Thanks!

Comment: But now i can`t save Select to the model.

Comment: @VolodymyrKirichinets Hmm, it looks like you should override `get_form` method too - you must convert initial value using `list()` function

Comment: @VolodymyrKirichinets can you give me full traceback?

Comment: Server is running -  traceback nothing to show, I just see error in admin field  "Enter a list of values." when I try  to save. And I edited question and add my views.py